# Flex: how to reset spark combo box with validator?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Below is a self-contained application you can run. It simply displays a spark combo box with a reset button. If you select an entry, such as "Red", then click on the "Reset Combo Box" button, the selected entry in the combo box is cleared. However, it should also remove any error message for the combo box, but this error message is not getting removed. A second click of the Reset button will remove the error.

Anyone know a solution that doesn't require a second click on the Reset button?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:NumberValidator id="valCB" source="{myCB}" 
                        property="selectedIndex" minValue="0" 
                        lowerThanMinError="This field is required."/>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
        import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
        import mx.validators.*;

        private function resetCB():void {
            valCB.enabled=false;   <!-- disable validator -->
            myCB.selectedIndex=-1; <!-- reset selected entry -->
            valCB.enabled=true;    <!-- enable validator -->
            myCB.errorString="";   <!-- clear error msg -->
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Form id="myForm">                
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout gap="-5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:FormItem label="Select a Color"  required="true">
        <s:ComboBox id="myCB" width="140" prompt="Select a Color"> 
            <s:dataProvider>
                <mx:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>Red</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Blue</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Green</fx:String>
                </mx:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:ComboBox>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Button label="Reset Combo Box" x="60" y="60" click="resetCB()"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug on Adobe's part to me, though I'm not sure if the intended behaviour would be for it to work on the first click, or to not work at all. You're setting the `selectedIndex` to a value not allowed by your validator, turning the validator on and expecting it not to validate. I'm not sure what I would expect to happen.

It might be better to just disable the validator in the `click` event, and re-enable it in a `change` event. Remove `valCB.enabled=true;` from the reset function (and `myCB.value = -1;`, since the value will already be -1):

```
private function resetCB():void {
    valCB.enabled=false;   <!-- disable validator -->
    myCB.errorString="";   <!-- clear error msg -->
}
```

and give the `ComboBox` a `change` event:

```
<s:ComboBox id="myCB" width="140" prompt="Select a Color" change="enableValidate()">
```

And then enable the validator in that event:

```
protected function enableValidate():void
{
    valCB.enabled=true;
}
```

Comment: I also tried setting the `lowerThanMinError=""` in resetCB(), hoping it would get set back to "This field is required" again when the validator was run, but it remained empty forever after. Was hoping for a simple solution. I expect the validator to always run, but just clear the error after the fact. Not sure what you mean by disable in the click and re-enable in a change (could you modify the code?).

Comment: Thanks CheeseWarlock, but without `myCB.selectedIndex=-1;` there is nothing to reset the selection in the combobox to empty. I think, in addition to your changes, if we just insert `myCB.selectedIndex=-1;` inside resetCB(), it should work.

Comment: Yes, it works now, but need to include `myCB.selectedIndex=-1;` inside resetCB();, along with your other changes. Thanks so much CheeseWarlock, I'm sure I wouldn't have thought of this solution myself.

Comment: +! from me; I didn't notice the inherent contradiction in the original code.  Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

You should set control errorString as empty. That should do the trick.

Comment: Actually I tried your code and surprisingly clearing error string didn't do the trick. Hmmm...

Comment: Yah, I set the errorString="" above but it only seems to help on the second click of the Reset button (not sure why).